# How to clear values of keys in redis

Tags: php, caching, redis, predis

I am running two instance of my php application, one is live and one is beta. i am using redis in my live server for caching data. i am storing article category as key and article id as values.

Recently by mistake i connected my beta server with the redis and it has messed redis cache. i mean it has added some other article ids in wrong keys. so now i started getting wrong data from redis.

my question is

> "is there any way to clear only values of the redis keys?"

i don't want to clear keys but only values of it.

i had gone through redis document and i found **flushAll**, **del** etc.. but based on doc it will delete my keys also it seems.

i am using predis php library to communicate with redis server.

can anybody help me to delete only values from redis server.

Comment: Depends on the type of value being stored for that key, but variants on `set <key> <value>` from the redis cli?

Comment: i am storing data something like : set technologies "10 20 30"

Comment: Then try `set technologies null`

Comment: If it's a list, then just `rpop technologies` until `get technologies` returns null

Comment: sorry its out of topic question how i can list key values pair in cli?

Comment: You can list the key using `keys *` where the `*` is simply a wildcarded key name.... `get <key>` will generally return the value - http://redis.io/commands#

Answer (score 1):

When you "clear" the value of a key, Redis will remove the key. Put differently, you can't have keys with no values.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this function

```
$redis->mset(array('key0' => '', 'key1' => ''));
```

Comment: Most likely, this is not what the OP wants. If you do this, the caching layer will probably return an empty string for the key. The OP needs the keys gone in order for the cache to get re-populated.